# Whitelisting URL's in Phonegap for Android Lollipop 5.0

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, android-5.0-lollipop, whitelist

This is making me pull my hair out, and so desperate to start testing in Android 5.*, so here goes.

First here is what I have:

**config.xml**

```
<access origin="*.google.com"/>
<access origin="*.gstatic.com"/>
<access origin="*.googleapis.com"/>
...
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    ...


    <meta   http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            content="default-src 'self' https://*.google.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <meta   http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            content="default-src 'self' https://*.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <meta   http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            content="default-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I have found that the same issue is described [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/iframe-issue-in-android-5-0-lollipop), and attempted to merge the suggestions found, along with some other advice from the [PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html), no success yet.

To be more specific to this issue, the resource I am trying to allow is Google Maps V3.  I'm certain I'm missing something small, would appreciate anything, even a simple suggestion.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Well spotted, @Fido, but unfortunately this has proven not to be the only issue.  I am now using the PhoneGap plugin as documented [here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3401), and replaced in my **config.xml** as such, but no improvement.  The funny thing I've noticed though is that the plugin does not show up as being used in the project's plugin summary (which I have now discovered exists).  So, I would say it is likely that despite the documentation, it is not able to pull this resource as it describes it should.

I will give anyone a chance to make any extra suggestions, but ultimately I may have to bite the bullet and do a local build as Fido suggests.

**UPDATE 2**

As it turned out, I hadn't pushed my config.xml to the repository properly, so it now reflects that I am using the [whitelist plugin provided by Corova](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3401), but hasn't helped. I will see if there are any plugins are around before I build local and use the other suggested plugin.

**UPDATE 3**

Good news; I was able to specify the NPM package of the same plugin from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist):

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" source="npm" />`

And as far as I can gather, it is the mirror as you suggested @Fido (correct me if I'm wrong) but the issue persists; I can only imagine that it is either my origins, allow-intents or Content-Security-Policy definitions are incorrect.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using cordova 4.0 and above make sure you have [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) plugin. My white lists stopped working until I used it.

Comment: I should probably remove my tag of cordova, as I've only started getting to these PhoneGap builds, and currently starting off with the [cloud](http://build.phonegap.com) service.  Can I just change the version attribute of the plugin node to 4 instead?

Comment: Cordova and Phonegap are essentially the same thing. Cordova is owned by Apache and is open source. Phonegap is owned by Adobe and is the cloud service built on-top of cordova. Anyway, all phonegap plugins are essentially cordova plugins. Long story short you most likely need this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to get whitelist working properly.

Comment: I just noticed a possible error. For phonegap plugins to be downloaded correctly during the remote build this line: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />` must actually be this `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />`

Comment: You'll have to forgive my ignorance @Fido, still learning, the only reason I clarified excluding cordova is because I understand, or at least I am under the impression that I am a bit more limited in terms of control using the cloud service.  How can I enable the plugin you suggested in my config.xml?  Is there a `<gap:plugin name="..."` line I can put insert? Or would I simply have to use the SDK to put it all together?

Comment: You might be right! I'll try that first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Cordova 4.0 and above you need to add [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) plugin to get your whitelists working poroperly.

In your case since you are using the phonegap build platform this line:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

Should actually be this:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

If the cloud service proves too limiting then you can use the CLI to install cordova plugins and then build and deploy locally.
More info on this appraoch [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). This approach requires more setup effort (e.g. getting the android sdk) but makes development in the long run much faster in my opinion.

Comment: Much appreciated, a good spot, will get on to try all of this asap and let you know the outcome!

Comment: [This](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html) provides more info on plugin retrieval using phonegap build.

Comment: Super appreciate the answer, Fido!  I'm not entirely out of the woods yet, but this has pretty much definitively answered this particular issue.  At the moment, it *seems* that the Content-Security-Policy has had to have a lot of corrections, and I'm getting just a plain White Screen (WSOD) now, but further evidence shows this relates to the PhoneGap auto-hide-splash-screen setting.  Also the getCurrentCoordinates is a bit flakey, but will experiment putting this on a timer test.

Comment: @Jester, are you still having issues? if so, what are they?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 : Hey that's my name! :) Thanks for asking! I've actually got everything sorted out now, and its working a treat.  I got led down a stray path which was weird; I found I could modify the CSP back and fourth, and a certain change on that gave me the WSOD, and reverting it gave the display back, and this was echoed in other forums, when in actual fact in a older commit I had broken the DOM with almost half missing! When I patched, both the DOM and CSP worked fine - thank god! Will let you guy's know if any other "flakey" problems :)

Comment: This might help: [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)  and [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)